# AWS LifeCycle Manager for Snapshot backup auto Deletion

Tags: amazon-web-services

How to create Policy Lifecycle manager only for Auto deletion for old snapshot backup.
While using Lifecycle manager it is giving me option for creation and than deletion through tags, however I have already scheduled python scripts in my environment for snapshot backup, I just wanted to use auto-deletion feature by using Life cycle manager in AWS environment.

Comment: Adding a comment so I can track.  I also am interested in the answer.